# Is there a relation between $\ker T^x, x \in \Bbb N$ and the dimension of the space?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ - Linear space.

$T$ - Linear transformation:

$$
T:V \to V
$$

$(1)$ Prove that $\forall k \in \Bbb N, k \geq 1$:

$$
\ker T \subseteq \ker T^2 \subseteq ... \subseteq \ker T^k \subseteq \ker T^{k+1} \subseteq...
$$

$(2)$ Prove that if $V$ has finite dimension, so $\exists m, \ker T^m = \ker T^{m+1}$

*My question is about $(2)$

---

Can someone explain the intuition for $(2)$?

Is it because there is some kind of connection between $T^x$ to the dimension of $T$?

Comment: Each kernel is a subspace of $V$, and the containment relations show the dimension never goes down, and it can only go up to at most the dimension of $V$, so ....

Comment: Do you mean that $kerT^2$ is a subspace and $kerT^3$ is a subspace of $V$ and so on. 
and if $kerT^x \subset kerT^{x+1}$ so the dimension of $kerT^{x+1}$ is at least 1 more than the dimension of $kerT^x$ but if $\forall k \in N$ i get $kerT^k \subset kerT^{k+1}$ i will get that $V$ is with infinite dimension?

Therfore, conclusion,  $\exists x \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall k > x: kerT^k = kerT^{k+1}$?

Comment: The inclusions are not strict, so the dimension doesn't necessarily go up – it just can't go down.

Comment: If what i conclude is not correct i dont think i understood you well. I see that the dimension cant go down, so it cant goes up forever because we are with finite dimension? if $\forall k \in \Bbb N, kerT^k \subset kerT^{k+1}$ we will get an infinite dimension for $V$?

Comment: Right, it can't go up forever because $V$ has finite dimension. I think it just confuses things to state it by assuming the inclusions are strict and deducing the dimension is infinite, there's no need to introduce that concept. Also, you don't have to assume all the inclusions are strict to get a contradiction, just that infinitely many of them are – but, why get bogged down in that?

Comment: Thank you for the help, so the key is that kerT is a subspace of V and a subspace always has equal or less dimension, if i understood you correctly

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is finite dimension, the *pigeonhole principle* shows there exists  $m<m_1\in\mathbf N$ such that $\dim\ker T^m=\dim\ker T^{m_1}$. Therefore, since these kernels are linearly ordered, we have $\ker T^m=\ker T^{m+1}=\dots=\ker T^m_1$. Let's show by induction that, for any $k\ge 0$, we have
$$\ker  T^m=\ker T^{m+1}=\dots=\ker T^{m+k}$$
 The initialisation is true for all $k\le m_1-m$.

Suppose now the assertion is valid for some $k>m_1-m$, and consider a vector $v\in\ker T^{m+k+1}$; this implies $T(v)\in\ker T^{m+k}$, hence by the inductive hypothesis, $T(v)\in\ker T^{m}$, so that $v\in\ker T^{m+1}=\ker T^{m}$.

Comment: Thank you Bernard but i would like to understand the intuition rather than technically see the prove. And i dont know what is the pigenhole principle (we didnt learn it).

Comment: Here we speak of Dirichlet's drawers principle: it is well known in combinatorics  and is quite intuitive: it simply says that if you have a chest of $n$  drawers and more than $n$ objects to put in, at least one drawer will receive more than $1$ object.

Comment: So shortly, we can say like what the one who helped me in the comments: V has dimension of n, and we have more than n powers, therefore, at least 2 T^x will get the same dimension?

Comment: Thhe intuition is simply that since the dimensions of subspaces are bounded by $\dim V$, and they're non-decreasing, they'll eventually all be equal.

Comment: Ok so its approve what we said in the comments, if i understood you well, because every $kerT^x$ is a subspace of V and a subspace cant have a dimention greater than the space, thank you

Comment: What the proof I posted adds is that the kernels are (strictly) increasing first, then stabilise. This is very important to know to compute efficiently the Jordan normal form of a matrix.